# Locating missing marriage records

Tags: england, marriage-records

For context, everything here is Pancras, London, England.

I have an ancestor (Harriet Deady, formerly Thompson, originally Gammon, my 2nd g. grandmother from Halifax, Nova Scotia, British North America) that I am confident remarried after her husband (Richard Thompson, my 2nd g. grandfather) passed away in 1898. She is present on some other contemporary records, has identical particulars, and I can find her in the 1911 census living with her new husband (John Deady), and the length of marriage as given suggests they married around 1905.

However, there is no record of any marriage in the BMD indexes. I have placed a search-based order with the GRO hoping they would search the actual records, but I've just been refunded, so presumably they're not in there at all.

John Deady was born in India but signed up to the Army at 14, and ended up in England by the end of his service in 1900, and was working as a railway porter in 1911. They lived in housing around Euston station in 1911, so I doubt they would have had the sort of money required to travel. Can't rule it out, of course, but I think it unlikely.

Does anyone have any suggestions on avenues I can explore to prove this marriage took place?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE. Where was John Deady born?  Is there any chance that the marriage may have taken place outside England and Wales?

Comment: John Deady was born in India but signed up to the Army at 14, and ended up in England by the end of his service in 1900, and was working as a railway porter in 1911. They lived in housing around Euston station in 1911, so I doubt they would have had the sort of money required to travel. Can't rule it out, of course, but I think it unlikely.

Comment: Have you found either John or Harriet in a 1901 census?

Comment: No, actually. He left the army in 1900, but signed up for an additional year in the reserves on the 27th of March 1900, leaving on the 26th March 1901. He has a sister listed as living in Little Clarendon St, St Pancras. Presumably who he went to stay with when he left the army. I'll go find her in the census and see if he's there as a transcription error or something.

Comment: John Deady's not there in 1901, but I found his sister's family and spent a few hours poking around back and forth looking for more data points that could shed some light. Alas, none to be found thus far.

Comment: Is it possible that he got sent to South Africa to fight in the Second Boer War, which ended in 1902? Also, did you find him in the 1891 census (Kent, Cheriton, District Royal Artillery)?

Comment: On page 2 of his 1875 enlistment, it gives his religion as Roman Catholic. That plus the name "Deady" sounds as though his family might originally be Irish. Googling "Irish in Victorian Bengal" gives some interesting results. If he _is_ Irish, then they may have gotten married in the Catholic church, in which case there should be a register somewhere.